# Understanding aptitude's behavior on a machine with multiple archives enabled

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, aptitude

I'm having to deal with a Debian server, which initially was Squeeze, I believe, but where administrator enabled several distributions:

```
deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free
deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/ experimental main contrib non-free
```

and specified in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`: `APT::Default-Release "testing";`.

As a result, when I'm asking aptitude or apt about state of a certain package it bears controversial testimony:

```
me@server: aptitude search emboss
i A emboss                                       - european molecular biology open software suite   

me@server: aptitude show emboss
Package: emboss                          
New: yes
State: not installed
Automatically installed: yes
...
```

`apt-cache show emboss` shows information on 4 copies of the package of interest ("emboss"), out of which one copy contains line `Status: install ok installed`, which means that it is installed, I assume.

```
Package: emboss
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: science
Installed-Size: 4020
Maintainer: Debian Med Packaging Team <debian-med-packaging@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 6.3.1-6
Depends: emboss-lib (= 6.3.1-6), libc6 (>= 2.7), libexpat1 (>= 1.95.8), libfontconfig1 (>= 2.8.0), libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1), libgd2-noxpm (>= 2.0.36~rc1~dfsg) | libgd2-xpm (>= 2.0.36~rc1~dfsg), libhpdf-2.1.0 (>= 2.1.0+dfsg), libjpeg62 (>= 6b1), libmysqlclient16 (>= 5.1.21-1), libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4), libpq5 (>= 8.4~0cvs20090328), libx11-6, libxpm4, zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4), emboss-data (= 6.3.1-6)
Recommends: primer3, dialign
Suggests: emboss-doc, emboss-test, embassy, clustalw
Description: the european molecular biology open software suite
 EMBOSS is a free Open Source software analysis package specially developed for
 the needs of the molecular biology (e.g. EMBnet) user community. The software
 automatically copes with data in a variety of formats and even allows
 transparent retrieval of sequence data from the web. Also, as extensive
 libraries are provided with the package, it is a platform to allow other
 scientists to develop and release software in true open source spirit. EMBOSS
 also integrates a range of currently available packages and tools for sequence
 analysis into a seamless whole. EMBOSS breaks the historical trend towards
 commercial software packages.
Homepage: http://emboss.sourceforge.net
```

My questions are:
1) How do I know, from which distribution (stable, testing, unstable, experimental) currently installed version of package was taken? How do I refer to it in commands (e.g. in `dpkg -L`)?
2) How aptitude commands (`show` and `search`) choose, which version of the package they should report? Why algorithms of `show` and `search` differ?

P.S. Please, don't reply that creating a mix of distributions is a bad practice. I totally agree, but still have to deal with that machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt-cache policy packagename_here` can tell you which version of a package is available in which repository.